# TS2322: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'never'

Tags: typescript

How I can fix this error without using @ts-ignore?

```
class Test {
    public field1!: Date;
    public field2?: Date;
    public field3?: string;
    public field4?: number;
}

const t = {field1: new Date(), field2: new Date()} as Test;

for(const field of ["field1", "field2"] as Array<keyof Test>) {
// error is in the next line: TS2322: Type 'Date' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    t[field] = new Date();
}
```

I understand why this problem appears but not understand how I can fix it in this situation with some type hints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you probably realized, `["field1", "field2"]` gets inferred as `string[]`, which is too wide for the compiler to guarantee safety inside the loop; `t` might not have a field corresponding to any given `string`.  By asserting that it is `Array<keyof Test>` you have narrowed it a bit, but still, not enough to guarantee safety; after all, we know `t` has fields of type `keyof Test`, but some of those properties must be of type `string`, not `Date`, so you can't safely assign a `Date`.

Since TypeScript 3.4 came out, the easiest way by far for you to proceed here is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/overview.html#const-assertions) and write `["field1", "field2"] as const`.  This essentially asks the compiler to infer the type of the array literal  to be the *narrowest type it can infer*, which is `readonly ["field1", "field2"]`; a [`readonly` tuple](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#readonly-tuples) of exactly two entries, which must be exactly the string literals `"field1"` and `"field2`", in that order.  That's narrower than you *need* to get type safety in the loop: `Array<"field1" | "field2">` would suffice; but it's not *too narrow* or anything, so you might as well use it:

```
for (const field of ["field1", "field2"] as const) {
    t[field] = new Date(); // okay
}
```

Looks good.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH0AOArgEYgCWw0AZqfCACYCMAhAFzQAiYS8A3FrvmJkK1WnQBMAfjadufbLkIlyVGvQDM06MgBOpAHYBzeQKXDVYgCxb9BALZF4O+QF8sWYAHt9yaCgC8aBb0DGz68ADuHFzwABQAlAA0wRJhkdHcCdAu0JBwiEjyWJSeOtCxXj4oovTQnpTQANoARDWMzcmtahLNALq5MJXI8Wj8uEiNbf2B4VGycfE80AD0y3UA1mAAnlguQA)

Answer (score 1):

That is because type-narrowing does not automatically happen when you are doing `["field1", "field2"] as Array<keyof Test>`, because, for example, `["field1", "field2", "field3"]` is also a valid subtype of `Array<keyof Test>`.

If you want to narrow the type, you will have to do it inside the for loop instead:

```
for (const field of Object.keys(t) as Array<keyof Test>) {
  // From here, TypeScript is able to narrow to type of `t[field]` to `Date`
  if (field === 'field1' || field === 'field2') {
    t[field] = new Date();
  }
}
```

[See example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=10&ssc=9&pln=10&pc=53#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAu0DeBYAUNH0AOArgEYgCWw0AZqfCACYCMAhAFzQAiYS8A3FrvmJkK1WnQBMAfjadufbLkIlyVGvQDM06MgBOpAHYBzeQKXDVYgCxb9BALZF4O%20QF8sWYAHt9yaCgC8aKL0DGz68ADuHFzwABQAlAA0FvTiYZHR3Aku0JBwiEjyWJSeOrEg8CjBdNCelNAA8kQAVvDASAB0ANbwAJ4QsUjxuTAAgjo6YL0APD29dfnIAHzDGAqk9bHV0P670ADk1Qz70AA%20pyk1u4GHahL7q-y4SADa1QC6O9DhUbJx8SZoG5MC4gA).

Comment: Thank you. Is there any another way to do not go through all keys?